# How to disable Checkbox after checking another checkbox in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, checkbox

How to disable the checkbox with the `name="check_no[]"` after checking the checkbox `name="check_yes[]"`?

```
<tr>
  <td colspan="" width="6%">
    <center>
      <input type="checkbox" name="check_yes[]" value="yes">
    </center>
  </td>
  <td colspan="" width="6%">
    <center>
      <input type="checkbox" name="check_no[]" value="no">
    </center>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `closest()` and `find()` to get the neighbouring child checkbox and then disable it using `prop()`, something like this:

```js
$('table :checkbox').change(function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').find(':checkbox').not(this).prop('disabled', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="" width="6%">
      <center>
        <input type="checkbox" name="check_yes[]" value="yes">
      </center>
    </td>
    <td colspan="" width="6%">
      <center>
        <input type="checkbox" name="check_no[]" value="no">
      </center>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It only works for the 1st row of the table, how about the succeeding rows?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("table [name='check_yes[]']").change(function() {
  if($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $("[name='check_no[]']").prop('disabled', true);
  }
});
```

This listens for any check_yes[] check and disables all other check_no[] on the page if it was checked

Answer (score 0):

```
function enab1() {
document.getElementById("check_no").disabled = true;
}
function enab2() {
document.getElementById("check_yes").disabled = true;
}
```

in your html code

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check_yes[]" value="yes" onclick="enab1()">
<input type="checkbox" name="check_no[]" value="yes" onclick="enab2()">
```

Hope this will works